# Do moderators have the ability to mark an answer as correct?

Tags: discussion, answers

I have noticed a lot of questions (normally by first time users) with perfect answers that are not marked as correct.

Can moderators mark these as correct or is there a way to nominate an answer for consideration?

Answer (score 7):

No, moderators can't change the accepted answer of a question. The only exception is that they can delete an accepted answer, but they can't set another answer as accepted.

Comment: Does deleting and undeleting an accepted answer actually wipe out the checkmark?

Comment: @badp Testing time!

Comment: @fredley SCIENCE

Comment: @badp I don't think so, but most users won't be able to see the accepted answer when it is deleted.

Comment: SCIENCE has been conducted, deleting an accepted answer removes the accept.